# R plotly total count

Tags: r, text, count, plotly

I have a plotly pie cart and a bar chart on my shiny dashboard and I was wondering if there is way to display 'total count' somewhere on the chart. For instance,

```
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo)
plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
```

I want to display 'Total Count = 57' in the plot somewhere

thanks,

Manoj Agrawal

Comment: Please provide the tab data or some version of it.

Comment: Revised the post with sample data. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:
The `slice()` function define where the text will be plotted.

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>%
  slice(which.min(SF_Zoo)) %>%
  add_annotations(paste("Total=", sum(SF_Zoo)), showarrow=F, y=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Jimbou. I was trying to add this to a pie chart but I couldn't figure it how to position it. I tried giving values of x and y and it keeps pasting it at the center of the pie chart. Also, how do I change the font size and make it bold?